# Is this a valid ufw rule or wrong syntax

Tags: ufw

Can I use a rule like this in ufw or it is impossible?

Sudo ufw allow from any to ip 1.1.1.1 port 5001:5999

Regards

Anders Yuran

Comment: Just example. I have two ip and want to deny most traffic on one.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite (at least not in ufw v. 0.36)

```
$ ufw --version
ufw 0.36
Copyright 2008-2015 Canonical Ltd.
```

- there doesn't appear to be an `ip` keyword; just specify the IP address after the `to` or `from` keywords
- the `m:n` port range syntax demands an explicit protocol specification

So

```
$ sudo ufw allow from any to ip 1.1.1.1 port 5001:5999
ERROR: Wrong number of arguments

$ sudo ufw allow from any to 1.1.1.1 port 5001:5999
ERROR: Must specify 'tcp' or 'udp' with multiple ports

$ sudo ufw allow from any to 1.1.1.1 port 5001:5999 proto tcp
Rule added
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that I probably have to have a to also in the rules for the other ip to not allow f.ex http on both ip?

Comment: OK that solved the problem